# How do I create a preg_match for numbers greater than 199?

Tags: php, regex, http-post, preg-match

I have an auction item for sale 'offer form' coded in PHP. I would like to create a preg_match string to return an error if any currency value entered into this form is less than 199 GBP. The formulation should allow special characters £, $, € and all letters of the alphabet to be input with the offer value. So this formula would accept/allow the following inputs - 199 or 199 GBP or 199gbp or £199 or $199 or GBP 199 or Euro199 etc..

So far my current string only restricts values entered if below '100' and it does not include the allowance for symbols and letters if entered into the value.

I would be very grateful if any of you out there could help me out? Here is my code so far -

```
} elseif (!preg_match('/^[-+]?[\p{Nd} .-]{3,30}$/', ($_POST['offer']))) {

$error_msg .= "Please enter an offer above £199 GBP! \n";
```

Updated this post as required to show more of script -

```
    // end score assignments
    # was there a reCAPTCHA response?
if (isset($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"])) {
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

unset($_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"]);
unset($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

        if (!$resp->is_valid) {
                # set the error code so that we can display it
                $error_msg .= $resp->error;
               }

}
    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['address']) || empty($_POST['postcode']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['mobile']) || empty($_POST['item']) || empty($_POST['offer'])) {
        $error_msg .= "Oops you've missed something out! - Please complete ALL (*) required fields.. \n";
        } elseif (!preg_match('/^[-+]?[\p{Nd} .-]{11,30}$/', ($_POST['mobile']))) {
                $error_msg .= "Please enter a valid mobile number! \n";
        } elseif (!preg_match('/^\s*(£|\$|GBP|Euro|gbp)?\s*(199|([2-9]\d\d+))$)|(^\s*(199|([2-9]\d\d+)\s*(£|\$|GBP|Euro|gbp)?)$/', ($_POST['offer']))) {
                $error_msg .= "&#149; Please enter an offer above £199 GBP!<br />&#149; Enter only numbers, no letters or symbols.<br /> \n";
    } elseif (strlen($_POST['name']) > 25) {
        $error_msg .= "The name field is limited at 25 characters. Your first initial and surname will do! \n";
    } elseif (!ereg("^[A-Za-z' -]*$", $_POST['name'])) {
        $error_msg .= "The name field must not contain special characters. \n";
    } elseif (!ereg("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,6})$",strtolower($_POST['email']))) {
        $error_msg .= "Please enter a valid e-mail address! \n";
    } elseif (!empty($_POST['url']) && !preg_match('/^(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+)(:(\d+))?\/?/i', $_POST['url'])) {
                $error_msg .= "Invalid website url.";

}

    if ($error_msg == NULL && $points <= $maxPoints) {
        $subject = $_REQUEST['domain'];

        $message = "You received an offer through your website: \n\n";
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
            $message .= ucwords($key) . ": $val \r\n";
        }


        if (strstr($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], "Win")) {
            $headers   = "From: $yourEmail \r\n";
            $headers  .= "Reply-To: {$_POST['email']}";
        } else {
            $headers   = "From: $yourWebsite <$yourEmail> \r\n";
            $headers  .= "Reply-To: {$_POST['email']}";
        }

        if (mail($yourEmail,$subject,$message,$headers)) {

$selectedProjects  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['projects']) && is_array($_POST['projects']) && count($_POST['projects']) > 0){
    $selectedProjects = implode(', ', $_POST['projects']);
}

$body .= 'Selected Projects: ' . $selectedProjects;

    $url = 'success.htm';
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">'; 

echo '<p><span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;color: green;">Your offer has been sent to us successfully, thank you!</p>

<p><span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;color: green;">We will be in touch with you shortly.</span> </p>';

        } else {
            echo '<p><span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;color: green;">Your mail could not be sent this time!</p>';
        }
    }
}
function get_data($var) {
    if (isset($_POST[$var]))
        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST[$var]);
}
if ($error_msg != NULL) {
    echo '<p><strong style="color: red;">ERROR:</strong><br />';
    echo nl2br($error_msg) . "</p>";
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var RecaptchaOptions = {    
theme : 'clean' 
}; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
(?:^\s*(?:£|\$|GBP|Euro|gbp)?\s*(?:199|1\d{3}\d*|(?:[2-9]\d\d+))$)|(?:^\s*(?:(?:199|1\d{3}\d*|(?:[2-9]\d\d+))\s*(?:£|\$|GBP|Euro|gbp)?)$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jV1dU7/4)

[image: Regular expression visualization]
Sample Code:

```
   else if (!preg_match('/(^\s*(?:£|\$|GBP|Euro|gbp)?\s*(?:199|1\d{3}\d*|(?:[2-9]\d\d+))$)|(?:^\s*(?:(?:199|1\d{3}\d*|(?:[2-9]\d\d+))\s*(?:£|\$|GBP|Euro|gbp)?)$)$)/', $_POST['offer'])) {
           $error_msg .= "&#149; Please enter an offer above £199 GBP!<br />&#149; Enter only numbers, no letters or symbols.<br /> \n";
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your very complex solution ;-O Wow! I'm not a programmer and I would be grateful if you could type the exact code that I would need to use by inserting it in to my existing string specifically for preg_match php? I have had a go already to try and make it work but what I have done has not worked, here is what I have - } elseif (!preg_match('/^\s*(£|\$|GBP|Euro|gbp)?\s*(199|([2-9]\d\d+))$)|(^\s*(199|([2-9]\d\d+)\s*(£|\$|GBP|Euro|gbp)?)$/', ($_POST['offer']))) {

Comment: @Mark , Post your PHP code and i'll try to write to give the code :)

Comment: Here is the section of PHP code that I am using but doesn't work. This is the only section that I need to fix, thanks - } elseif (!preg_match('/^\s*(£|\$|GBP|Euro|gbp)?\s*(199|([2-9]\d\d+))$)|(^\s*(199|([2-9]\d\d+)\s*(£|\$|GBP|Euro|gbp)?)$/', ($_POST['offer']))) {

                $error_msg .= "&#149; Please enter an offer above £199 GBP!<br />&#149; Enter only numbers, no letters or symbols.<br /> \n";

Comment: @Mark , edit your question and post the whole code please

Comment: As requested I have added as much of the script as possible for you, I hope this helps ;-) Please see my original now extended post.

Comment: @Mark , added code to answer, replace the suitable `elseif` block with the one posted in the answer

Comment: Thank you Pruthvi, it appears to work now although it does not accept the numbers 1000-1999 and 10000-19999 and 100000-199999. Please could you show me how I could change the code to allow these values too? I would also like it to allow for currency separation ie. 1,000 or 10,000 or 250.00 or 2500.00 or 2,500.00 Is this possible?

Comment: @Mark , I updated the answer accordingly and fixed the bug, it'll now accept all the numbers you mentioned

Comment: Unfortunately that appears to have broken the code, I can't appear to make it work with any values now! ;-) Any ideas appreciated? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I appear to have been using the wrong code as it was hidden in the 'edited 2 days ago' section, instead of being on this front page. However your newest code still seems to have gone a bit backwards as it won't now accept the following important formats - £1,450 (£ and , together) or 2,450 (, a comma) or 199.00 (. a decimal place). Are you able to adjust it to accept these too for me please? thanks.